# Sum up area left "underneath" polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, field-calculator

I have an area shape layer and multiple other area shape layers. Now I would like to calculate how much space (square kilometers or percentage of area) of the polygons of this area layer is NOT covered by the other layers. Some of the other layers are overlapping so it isn't as easy as to substract these areas.

Is this possible and if yes - does anyone here know how?

best regards
desputin

Answer (score 2):

You could first **dissolve** the layer with the overlapping polygons and then run **intersect** of the dissolved layer and the other layer.

Then you can simply compare the area values.